# Add horizontal and vertical scroll bars to NSView for MacOS app using XCode Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsview, macos-mojave

I am new to macOS standalone application development and I am working on fixing the issue in our existing application. I am running with an issue where the controls inside NSView are getting cut off at bottom and right side of NSView..I am using Xcode 11.3 in macOS Mojave 10.14

I would like to implement scroll bars horizontally and vertically to NSView so that i can be able to view the controls that are getting cut off at the bottom and right side of NSView. Can you please suggest on how to implement scrolling for MacOS NSView?

Comment: Use UIScrollView (oops, that is for iOS) ... for macos use NSScrollView

Comment: Enlarge the window or put the `NSView` inside a `NSScrollView`. Is the `NSView` loaded from a Storyboard?

Comment: @Willeke Yes.. NSView is loaded from a story board. Can you please suggest on how to put NSView inside a NSScrollView?

Comment: Does the view have a superview?

Comment: Yes the view has a superview which is also an NSView.

Comment: @Willeke Can you please suggest on how the scroll bars can be implemented for NSView?

Answer (score 0):

[NSScrollView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsscrollview) provides scroll bars.

The controls inside NSView are cut off, example:

[image]

Select the view in IB. Choose menu Editor -> Embed In -> Scroll View

If scrollbars are visible (Setting in System Prefs):

[image]

If scrollbars are invisible:

[image]

Resize the `NSScrollView` if needed and add constraints between the scroll view and its superview or sibling views.

Enlarge the Custom View and constrain the size of the Custom View by adding size constraints or constraints between the Custom View and its subviews.

Constrain the location of the Custom View to the topleft of its superview to remove the layout errors.

[image]

Build, run. The view is scrolled to the bottom. If you want to start scrolled to the top then create a subclass of `NSView`, override `isFlipped` and return `true`. Set the class of the Custom View in IB to this class.

```
override var isFlipped: Bool {
    get {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: As per step #2 will the NSScrollView gets added automatically ? And as per step #3 do we need to resize the scroll view and add constraints in the IB itself or through programatically. Please suggest

Comment: Yes embed in scroll view to my view. Scrolls still not getting appeared.. Anything needs to be done still

Comment: I'll add images.

Comment: Can you please add the images regarding the process that needs to be done for the implementation of scroll bars to NSView?

Comment: I have implemented the steps as mentioned by embedding the scroll view, setting the size of the scroll view and adding constraints but still the scrolls are not getting appeared. Is there any problem related to the addition of the constraints ? Can you please share the constraints that you have provided?

Comment: Is the view scrollable? While debugging in Xcode choose Menu Debug -> View Debugging -> Capture View Hierarchy. Does the Custom View fit inside its superview?

Comment: No the view is not scrollable, Yes the custome view gets fit inside the super view

Comment: If the Custom View fits inside its superview then there's nothing to scroll. If you want to see disabled scroll bars then set Show scroll bars to Always in the System Prefs.

Comment: Sorry i had read your comment wrong... custom view has lots of controls that are getting cut off at the bottom and right side of view..

Comment: If the controls are clipped by the custom view then enlarge the custom view. This wasn't in the answer, my bad.

Comment: Can you please share the sample code you have done for the implementation so that i can compare and check on what is actually missing out

Comment: Here's the storyboard: http://www.filedropper.com/mainstoryboard

Comment: Thank you for the storyboard. I am looking into it . If i have any quereis i will let you know.. Thanks a lot